# acceder a un view que se encuentra en un fragment desde activity?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Quiero acceder desde la actividad principal a un Button que se encuentra en un fragment mediante este codigo:

```
Button button = blankFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.btnFragment);
```

pero me da el siguiente error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.brynner.comunicationfragmentactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
```

Alguien porfavor podria ayudarme, les dejo el codigo completo.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
BlankFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

private BlankFragment blankFragment;
private EditText editTextActivity;
private Button buttonActivity, buttonConnectFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    blankFragment = new BlankFragment();

    editTextActivity = findViewById(R.id.edtxtActivity);
    buttonActivity = findViewById(R.id.btnActivity);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frameContainer, blankFragment).commit();

    Button button = blankFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.btnFragment);
    button.setText("Conectado");

}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de varios intentos ya pude resolver el problema dejare la respuesta por si mas alla alguien lo necesita.

El problema es que el codigo:

```
 Button button = blankFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.btnFragment);
```

solo funciona si esta dentro de un `OnClickListener()` de lo contrario siempre dara error.

Comment: recuerda aceptar tu respuesta en cuanto te sea posible

Comment: así los demás identificamos que ya esta resulta la pregunta +1